# C# - Type objects of constructed classes

Tags: c#, generics, types

I've read that reference types all use the same constructed class:

> Generics work somewhat differently for reference types. The first time a generic type is constructed with any reference type, the runtime creates a specialized generic type with object references substituted for the parameters in the MSIL. Then, every time that a constructed type is instantiated with a reference type as its parameter, regardless of what type it is, the runtime reuses the previously created specialized version of the generic type. This is possible because all references are the same size. ([Generics in the Run Time (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx))

However when calling GetType() on constructed objects based on the same generic with different type parameters, two different types are recieved. Where A and B are both classes, and RefType is a generic:

```
RefType<A> a = new RefType<A>();
RefType<B> b = new RefType<B>();
Console.WriteLine("a type is "+a.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("b type is "+b.GetType());
```

results in:

```
"a type is RefType`1[A]"
"b type is RefType`1[B]"
```

Does this mean that the CLR handles the creation of Type objects for different constructed types even when there is no "real" specialized instantiation?
Is there a way to see directly what is and isn't generated by the CLR?

Comment: The *types* are still very much distinct. What the text is trying to say (which it could do in a clearer fashion, and there's a lot of other bad writing in there) is that the actual code used to implement these types can be shared for all instantiations with reference types. This is an implementation detail that's usually of little concern to programmers, though. You'd need to hook up a debugger and check jitted code to see this; I'm not sure there's any way on the C# level to verify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the CLR handles the creation of Type objects for different constructed types even when there is no "real" specialized instantiation?

Yes. Consider that run-time type checks are an important part of the language.

```
var x = new List<string>() as List<object>;
```

This is supposed to initialise `x` to `null`. If the run-time type information for `new List<string>()` had somehow lost the generic type parameter, this couldn't work.

> Is there a way to see directly what is and isn't generated by the CLR?

```
class G<T> { public void f() { } }
class A { }
class B { }
struct C { }
struct D { }
enum E : int { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<object>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<string>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<A>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<B>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<C>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<D>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<E>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(G<int>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle.Value);
}
```

You will see that `G<object>.f`, `G<string>.f`, `G<A>.f` and `G<B>.f` have the same method handle, but `G<C>.f`, `G<D>.f`, `G<E>.f` and `G<int>.f` all have different ones. Not even `G<E>.f` and `G<int>.f` share the implementation.

Comment: For completeness (or as an exercise to the reader), you can verify that `G<string>` shares its implementation with the other reference types, while `G<int>` shares implementation with neither the reference types, nor `G<C>`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the suggestion, added, as well as some other cases.

Answer (score -1):

The `Type` objects give a type information at a high level of abstraction and tell you what the type is logically, whereas the implementation of generics is a low-level detail, that you should not rely on. Implementation details can always change.

`T<A>` and `T<B>` are two different types and therefore they must be described by to different `Type` objects. This is because a `Type` object not only yields information for `T<>`, but also for `A` or `B`, i.e. for the generic type parameters. The fact that the 2 types share the same code base makes no difference.

`Type` objects belong to the API. You can use this information in your code. The `Type` class might be extended in future to reflect new features of the language, but this is not a breaking change.

It is good to know the implementation details when you want to write efficient code. Some low-level tools (O/R-mappers, code weavers etc.); however, do sometimes depend on implementation details.

Comment: Useful advice, but not an answer to the question. Sometimes you want to dig into the implementation details.